# React issue - Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expression, function-call, array.prototype.map

I keep getting the error message "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" in my code, I think it is because I have an if inside my map but I have tried a few ways and I cant seem to make the code work.

I am trying to display information returned from my API, but I only want to display messages that have been sent when the ID length is equal to 7.

Example of the information returned from my API

```
"message_Subjects": [
    {
"subjectId": 1,
        "userId": 1234567,
        "subject": "test subject 1",
        "message_Chain": [
            {
                "messageBody": "TEST",
                "sentFromId": 1234567
            },
            {
                "messageBody": "Reply to the first message from another user",
                "sentFromId": 654321
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

This is my code

```
return (
  <div>
    {Data?.message_Subjects?.map((sub) => (
      <ul>
        <li>Subject = {sub.subject}</li>
        {sub.message_Chain.map((chain) => 
          {if(chain.sentFromId.length=== 7) (
          <ul>
            <li>message = {chain.messageBody}</li>
            <li>sent by = {chain.sentFromId}</li>
          </ul> )}
        )}
      </ul>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix javascript and jsx this way

```
return (
  <div>
    {Data?.message_Subjects?.map((sub) => (
      <ul>
        <li>Subject = {sub.subject}</li>
        {sub.message_Chain.map((chain) => {
          if(chain.sentFromId.length=== 7) (
            <ul>
              <li>message = {chain.messageBody}</li>
              <li>sent by = {chain.sentFromId}</li>
            </ul>
           )
          }
        )}
      </ul>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

When not used as an arrow function body, the following is not a proper javascript instruction, but an expression (has a value but does nothing, so it cannot be the body of an if statement):

```
       <ul>
        <li>message = {chain.messageBody}</li>
        <li>sent by = {chain.sentFromId}</li>
      </ul>
```

Just add a return for making it an expression (as expected in an if block) and allow the code to compile properly:

```
      return (
        <ul>
          <li>message = {chain.messageBody}</li>
          <li>sent by = {chain.sentFromId}</li>
        </ul>
       );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `return` after your condition.

```js
{
  if(chain.sentFromId.length === 7) {
    return (
          <ul>
            <li>message = {chain.messageBody}</li>
            <li>sent by = {chain.sentFromId}</li>
          </ul>)
  }
}
```

By the way, it's also better to explicitly handle the `else` case, by returning `null` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use conditional rendering for this cases:

```js
return (
    <div>
        {Data?.message_Subjects?.map((sub) => (
            <ul>
                <li>Subject = {sub.subject}</li>
                {sub.message_Chain.map(
                    (chain) =>
                        chain.sentFromId.length === 7 && (
                            <ul>
                                <li>message = {chain.messageBody}</li>
                                <li>sent by = {chain.sentFromId}</li>
                            </ul>
                        )
                )}
            </ul>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

Anything else, let me know

Answer (score 1):

In your code using `if ()` is not a valid `conditional rendering`. Try like

```
return (
  <div>
    {Data?.message_Subjects?.map((sub) => (
      <ul>
        <li>Subject = {sub.subject}</li>
        {sub.message_Chain.map(
          (chain) =>
            chain.sentFromId.length === 7 && (
              <ul>
                <li>message = {chain.messageBody}</li>
                <li>sent by = {chain.sentFromId}</li>
              </ul>
            )
        )}
      </ul>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```